# Fitch proofs help?

Tags: proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

I'm new to logic and can see how to write these out informally, but need some help seeing how they should be translated into formal proofs in Fitch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
|  ~Dodec(a) -> Large(a)
|  Large(d) -> (Large(b) v Large(c)
|  Large(b) -> ~Large(d)
|_ Dodec(a) -> ~Large(c)
:
|  Large(d) -> Large(a)
```

You seek to derive a conditional.  So you should use *conditional introduction*. Thus assume `Large(d)` aiming to derive `Large(a)`.

Having made that assumption you may use *conditional elimination* on the second premise, to derive a disjunction.  So you should use *disjunction elimination*; which is a "proof by cases" structure.

```
|  ~Dodec(a) -> Large(a)
|  Large(d) -> (Large(b) v Large(c))
|  Large(b) -> ~Large(d)
|_ Dodec(a) -> ~Large(c)
|  |_ Large(d)
|  |  Large(b) v Large(c)              ->E
|  |  |_ Large(b)
|  |  |  :
|  |  |  Large(a)
|  |  +
|  |  |_ Large(c)
|  |  |  :
|  |  |  Large(a)
|  |  Large(a)                          v E
|  Large(d) -> Large(a)                 ->I
```

And you should continue on in that vein.

---

```
|  Ax (Dodec(x) -> SameCol(x, a))
|_ SameCol(a, c)
:
|  Ax (Dodec(x) -> SameCol(x, c))
```

Now you seek to derive a universal statement. So use *universal introduction*: assume a fresh arbitrary term (let's say `b`) and derive the predicate in its context.

The predicate is a conditional statement, so use *conditional introduction* to derive it.  Thus assume `Dodec(b)` aiming to derive `SameCol(b, c)`.

To do this you need to invoke an analytical consequence, that `(SameCol(a,c) & SameCol(b, a)) -> SameCol(b, c)` may be used as an axiomatic schema.